# Trying to style Qt QML items by inserting child styling item

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I'm trying different approaches to styling a QT's app QML items. My goal is to:

- limit the amount of code in the main files (hide all styling stuff in styling files, unlike in the Style Singleton approach)
- not have to define every single type of item I'm going to use (unlike in the Custom Component approach)
- possibly be able to mix and match different pre-defined styles in a single item.

Maybe there is a clear strategy to get this, I just didn't read about it yet. And maybe it doesn't make any sense anyway :-)

I've been playing with the idea of defining different components, one for each style type I want to define. The idea is to:
- define a component which is going to modify its parent
- insert that component where I want to adopt that specific style

A first approach relies on some javascript calls:

MyStyle.qml:

```
Item {
  Component.onCompleted: {
    parent.color = "lightblue"
    parent.radius = 5
    parent.border.width = 3
    parent.border.color = "black"
  }
}
```

And in my main code:

```
    Rectangle {
      id: testRectangle
      anchors.fill: parent
      MyStyle {}
    }
```

This gives me the result I want, but it doesn't feel right:

- I'd like for the styling to be applied statically, once and for all
- if I start using this all over the place, won't I see artifacts when objects get created, and slow down my interface?

So I tried this too:

MyRectangleStyle.qml:

```
Item {
  property Rectangle styleTarget
  styleTarget.color: "lightblue"
  styleTarget.radius: 5
  styleTarget.border.width: 3
  styleTarget.border.color: "black"
}
```

and in my main code:

```
    Rectangle {
      id: testRectangle
      anchors.fill: parent
      MyStyle {styleTarget: testRectangle}
    }
```

But:

- well, it doesn't work :-)  (no warnings though, qml simply doesn't load)
- and I'm sort of back to having to define every single type of items I'm going to use.

So, is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do here? Thanks!

Comment: I think you are going to have some difficulties doing it this way. For example, how would you style things as highlighted buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second method does not work because your Component sets properties to an item that does not necessarily exist at the time of creating the Component, instead it sets the property when the styleTarget changes. On the other hand, it is not necessary for MyStyle to be an Item since it is not shown, instead use QtObject, and finally to generalize your method change `property Item styleTarget` to`property Rectangle styleTarget`:

```
QtObject {
    property Item styleTarget
    onStyleTargetChanged: {
        styleTarget.color = "lightblue"
        styleTarget.radius = 5
        styleTarget.border.width = 3
        styleTarget.border.color= "black"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it indeed works. But is this second method any better than the first one? Might I see artifacts when the different items are created and first displayed (will I see "glitches" in regard to the property affected), or does this happen even before the target item is first displayed?
And do you know of other methods that would be better suited for styling a QML app? Thank you.

Comment: @Will59 I do not think that it generates problems, the painting is done for all the items at the same time as well that it is optimized so it should not have problems. Or do you have millions of Items visible in an instant of time? If you do not have it then the optimization you want is called micro-optimization that does not help at all, and on the contrary it is a waste of time. Read https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99445/is-micro-optimisation-important-when-coding

Comment: @Will59 The difference to the first method is that your Style can be applied to another Item (obviously the style of the initial Item will be removed).